# KDB becoming unresponsive due to segmentation fault error

Tags: segmentation-fault, kdb

Getting segmentation fault error while KDB is running and it becomes unresponsive after this. It happens randomly.

> Sorry, this application or an associated library has encountered a
> fatal error and will exit.  If known, please email the steps to
> reproduce this error to tech@kx.com with a copy of the kdb+ startup
> banner and the info printed below. Thank you. SIGSEGV: Fault address

Core file which gets generated after the crash, has the following line repeated several times.

> Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 0, should be
> 2,3 or 4)

What can cause this? Can the Dwarf error cause this? Can low memory in the machine cause segmentation fault ?

Answer (score 2):

There's really only two things you can do when hitting seg faults with kdb:

1. Upgrade to the newest build of the kdb version you're currently running. Or better yet, upgrade to the newest build of the most current version.
2. Email tech@kx.com giving them as much detail as you can (note - first thing they may ask you to do is number 1 above)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Terry's answer - if you are loading any C libraries using `2:` then it could be runaway code there that's causing the issue when run from kdb-space.